# NSTableView cell editing: where to perform post-editing operations?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I modify the source data of a `NSTableView` by directly selecting the cells (`NSTextFieldCell`) and editing the text in it.

I need to perform some operations on a cell before and after a cell is edited.
I perform such operations before the editing in:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
```

But where can I perform the operations post editing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let google search for *nstableview edit change* and you will get a lot of detailed answers.

To make it short: use (some of) the following (and similar) delegate methods:

```
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)obj
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldEndEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor
```

and test them to show what are appropriate for your application:

```
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)obj
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [obj userInfo];
    NSTextView *aView = [userInfo valueForKey:@"NSFieldEditor"];
    NSLog(@"controlTextDidEndEditing %@", [aView string] );
}

- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [aNotification userInfo];
    NSTextView *aView = [userInfo valueForKey:@"NSFieldEditor"];
    NSLog(@"controlTextDidChange >>%@<<", [aView string] );
}

- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldEndEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor
{
    NSLog(@"control: textShouldEndEditing >%@<", [fieldEditor string] );
    return YES;
}
```

You can do this because the cells of the `NSTableView` are `NSTextFieldCell`s;

Answer (score 5):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDataSource/tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
   setObjectValue:(id)anObject
   forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn
              row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
```

Quoted from: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingCellTables/PopulatingCellTables.html

> For your app to edit the content of an NSCell-based table view, you
>   implement the tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row: data source
>   protocol method. This method is similar to
>   tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:, which provides the data for
>   the table view, but instead of requesting that you return a value for
>   the specified row and column, it provides the new value for that row
>   and cell